# Powershell balance array elements

Tags: powershell

(PS 101 newbie here)
I want to make a powershell script to import-csv a simple "folder,computername" file (generated by an app) where the folder will have 8 possible values (catchall,sun,mon,tue...sat).  1 value is a catch all and the other 7 are days of the week.  I want to make a list of computer names from the catch all group and export them to 7 files for the days of the week so that the resulting files make the 7 days balanced (so count each day of the week to know which ones need more items).  My app will import the 7 files and then later generate a new systems.csv file.

`$computers = import-csv “Systems.csv”
$newsched = $computers | Group "folder"`

This gets me the counts but I don't get how to take the results and use them for the loops.

I would then take the count of catchall and /7 it, then count how many each day of the week has a and loop where I export-csv the catch all elements to the appropriate day of the week file to keep them balanced as much as possible.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=powershell+loops

Comment: Even after reading several times, I don't get **what** you want to balance **how**. You really should show more details and expected outcome in your [edit]ed question.

Answer (score 0):

this is an OLD bit of code that takes an array of items and generates a set of equal-as-possible batches. if i was to rewrite it, instead of an array of strings, i would likely use a hashtable containing `Key = $BatchNumber` & `Value = $ArrayOfItems`. [*grin*]

however, it does demo one way to split a list into several smaller lists that are nearly the same size.

```
#$GroupList = "test1", "test2", "test3"
#$GroupList = "test1", "test2", "test3", "test4", "test5", "test6"
#$GroupList = "test1", "test2", "test3", "test4", "test5", "test6", "test7", "test8"
$GroupList = "test1", "test2", "test3", "test4", "test5", "test6", "test7", "test8", "test9", "test10", "test11"

$MaxPerBatch = 4
$Delimiter = ", " # one comma plus one space

$Batches = @()

Write-Output "----------"

$NextBatch = ""
$Remaining = $GroupList.Count
$Count = 0

foreach ($Group in $GroupList) {
    $Count++
    if (($Count -lt $MaxPerBatch) -and ($Remaining -gt 0)) {
        $NextBatch += $Group + $Delimiter
    }
    else {
        $NextBatch += $Group
        $Batches += $NextBatch
        $NextBatch = ""
        $Count = 0
    }
    $Remaining--
    if ($Remaining -eq 0) {
        $NextBatch = $NextBatch.TrimEnd($Delimiter)
        $Batches += $NextBatch
    }

}


Write-Output "batch[es] of groups = $($Batches.Count)"
Write-Output ""
Write-Output "collection displayed below ..."
$Batches

Write-Output "++++++++++"
```

output ...

```
----------
batch[es] of groups = 3

collection displayed below ...
test1, test2, test3, test4
test5, test6, test7, test8
test9, test10, test11
++++++++++
```